# Different screen sizes layout

Tags: android, layout, size, screen, screen-density

I created the different layout folders in order to support different screen sizes and densities (layout-small-ldpi, layout-ldpi, layout-mdpi, layout-hdpi, layout-xhdpi, layout-large,  layout-large-mdpi,  layout-xlarge)

And I also created a folder "layout-v11" and placed (layout-sw320dp-ldpi, layout-sw320dp-mdpi, layout-sw320dp-hdpi, layout-sw480dp, layout-sw600dp,  layout-sw720dp) in it.

But still not getting the desired layout (on Samsung S2).what can i do???
Please help.

Comment: What technology this question is related to?

Comment: android development for sure :)